# rabbitmq : message is not consumed by consumer , but publisher is able to publish message

Tags: spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using rabbitmq to for messaging in my service. Lets suppose there are 2 micro service A and B.

there are more 3 exchange and respective queue is there in between.

A is publisher and B is consumer here. while sending message from A it is successfully updating in queue( able to see in console queue is increases). But here consumer is not able to receive messages. previously it was working.

but for other exchange and queue , consumer is working fine.

I tried purze the queue and restarted application , didnt helped me. there is always 4 unached message in queue and rest is ready to Go. finally I deleted queue and exchange and respective routing key and recreated the same. then all working fine..

Can any one help me here what happened to this. Why it didnt worked?

Comment: Such problems are generally caused by the thread stuck somewhere in user code. Next time, take a thread dump to see what the threads are doing.

Comment: thanks for comment @GaryRussell ..thread for listener was cosumes 2-3 messages and stop listening. its states shows , it is runnable ..but behaves like it is dead :P .. next time i will take care

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when some failure occur for message processing then if we throw error. it stucks there so go in infinite loop(queue-> processing -> queue > .....) if method keep throwing error.

for other messages who all are in queue, by increasing the batch concurrency we can execute the other. but unack message will be there.that will only go if someone stop consumer..

Now I have one question can i set limit retry for unacked message processing. if some one knows about it then can help here.